# ValueEventListener stops working after a while of firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `ValueEventListener` to detect the data changes in `firebase`. I am experiencing a strange situation in which my app is able to add and get data within the app when data changed successfully but my app is not able to read data from firebase database if it is installed in other devices even if the data change has occurred.

My app works perfectly on both devices for the first day of installation after that `ValueEventListener` stops responding on the app of other devices.

**here is the code to set data to firebase database:**

```
public class FirebaseSync extends Service {
FirebaseDatabase fd;
DatabaseReference drr;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    fd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(FirebaseSync.this).registerReceiver(fReceive, new IntentFilter("FIRE"));
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(FirebaseSync.this).registerReceiver(fCity, new IntentFilter("FCITY"));
    drr = fd.getReference("users").child("key").child("city");
    drr.setValue("--");
}



private BroadcastReceiver fReceive = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent != null){

            FireData fireData = new FireData(distance, speed, time, status);
            DatabaseReference dr = fd.getReference("users").child("key");
            dr.setValue(fireData, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                    Log.i("FIREME","Value was set. Error = "+databaseError);                      
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(FirebaseSync.this).unregisterReceiver(fReceive);
}
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

**Code to get data from database:**

```
public class Fire extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef, cref;
boolean connected;
ValueEventListener listener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fire);

    connected = false;

    cref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    cref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class) != null){
                connected = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);

                if (connected){
                    firest.setText("Connected");
                }else {
                    firest.setText("Disconnected");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            firest.setText("Listener was cancelled");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    myRef = database.getReference("users").child("key");

    myRef.keepSynced(true);

    listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            try {
                double di = dataSnapshot.child("dis").getValue(Double.class);
                double sp = dataSnapshot.child("spe").getValue(Double.class);
                String ti = dataSnapshot.child("ti").getValue(String.class);
                boolean st = dataSnapshot.child("sta").getValue(Boolean.class);
                String ci = dataSnapshot.child("cit").getValue(String.class);
                                                    distance.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.distT), dista, units));
                speed.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.speedT), speeda));
                time.setText(timea);
                cityText.setText(cityN);


            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText(Fire.this, "something wrong happened at read value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    myRef.addValueEventListener(listener);        
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (myRef != null && listener != null){
        myRef.removeEventListener(listener);

    }

}
}
```

*I have also added SHA1 debug and release key on firebase console, but it also doesnt worked out.*

**Database Permission:**

```
  {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

**App Gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.adarsh.epoch"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
         testInstrumentationRunner        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
         }
         buildTypes {
         release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles   getDefaultProguardFile('proguardandroid.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

        dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
         implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-  layout:1.1.3'
          testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
          androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
           androidTestImplementation   'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


            implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
            implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
            implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
             implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'


}
```

It has been a week and I didn't got any solution.

Comment: When you are setting the value is it written to the database? If yes, please add your database structure.

Comment: Are you getting the activity stopped after a day? E.g. can you log the onStop event and see if you're clearing the listener? Does the onCancelled event fire? Does the value event fire with an exception?

Comment: No, the listener lifecycle is handled properly. I think I have figured out the issue. Actually after scratching my head for a week I have find out that my Android studio is not connected with Firebase, the Firebase tool under Tools section in Android Studio, after doing so my app suddenly started working again. I will let you know the status.